# Chapter 4.3.1 table 4.2 and Equation (4.13), (4.14) from Pearl et al. "Causal Inference in Statistics: A Primer"

Tags: probability, causality, structural-equation-modeling, dag

$\begin{equation}\begin{split} X & = u_{1} \\ Z & = a X + u_{2} \\ Y & = b Z \end{split}\end{equation}$

| $u_{1}$ | $u_{2}$ | $X(u)$ | $Z(u)$ | $Y(u)$ | $Y_{0}(u)$ | $Y_{1}(u)$ | $Z_{0}(u)$ | $Z_{1}(u)$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ab | 0 | a |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | b | b | (a+1)b | 1 | a+1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | a | ab | 0 | ab | 0 | a+1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | a+1 | (a+1)b | b | (a+1)b | 1 | a+1 |

Assuming that a=1,
$\begin{equation}\begin{split} E[Y_{X=1} | Z=1] & = b \Big( 1 + \frac{P(u_{1}=0)P(u_{2}=1)}{P(u_{1}=0)P(u_{2}=1) + P(u_{1}=1)P(u_{2}=0)} \Big) \\ E[Y_{X=0} | Z=1] & = b \Big( \frac{P(u_{1}=0)P(u_{2}=1)}{P(u_{1}=0)P(u_{2}=1) + P(u_{1}=1)P(u_{2}=0)} \Big) \end{split}\end{equation}$

How can I derive the expression $E[Y_{X=1} | Z=1] = b \Big( 1 + \frac{P(u_{1}=0)P(u_{2}=1)}{P(u_{1}=0)P(u_{2}=1) + P(u_{1}=1)P(u_{2}=0)} \Big)$ and $E[Y_{X=0} | Z=1] = b \Big( \frac{P(u_{1}=0)P(u_{2}=1)}{P(u_{1}=0)P(u_{2}=1) + P(u_{1}=1)P(u_{2}=0)} \Big)$?

Comment: Aren't all the rows of your table equi-probable? If they are not equi-probable, it would seem that you cannot reduce the expression, except to say, as Pearl does, that the first expression is larger than the second.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Perhaps I wrote the question wrong, so I expressed 'calculate' as 'derive the expression'.

Comment: @vinsh77 Write down $E[Y_{X=1} | Z=1]$ using directly the expected value and conditional probability definitions then use information from the table - second and third rows are relevant due to your condition $Z=1$ and given that $a=1$.